# Can't make a single select with a Switch or a RadioListTile flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, radio-button

i'm trying to make an Extra Food Items List it's for a Delivery App. The module of restaurants requiere these , but my issue is when I use a RadioListTile or a SwitchListTile it is possible to select more than one option, all the data is from an API where the Admin of some restaurant put the products. What i try to do is to make a ListView. separated for the Extra Groups (eg."Presa") and my Extras are the products or toppings that some product can have

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return SwitchListTile.adaptive(
  activeColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
 // checkColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
  value: widget.extra.checked,
  onChanged:(value) {
    setState(() {
      //widget.extra.checked = value;
      widget.extra.checked = !widget.extra.checked;
      widget.onChanged();
      Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 200),(){
        Navigator.pop(context);
      });
      widget.onSelectedExtra;

    });
  },
  title:  Text(
    widget.extra?.name,
    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline3.merge(TextStyle(
        color: Theme.of(context).shadowColor,
        fontSize: 16
    )),
    textAlign: TextAlign.start,
  ),
  subtitle: widget.extra.price == 'null' || widget.extra.price == null || widget.extra.price == '0' || widget.extra.price == 0
      ? Helper.getPrice(0, context, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4.merge(TextStyle(
      color: Theme.of(context).accentColor
  )),)
      :Helper.getPrice(widget.extra.price, context, style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4.merge(TextStyle(
      color: Theme.of(context).accentColor
  )),),
);
```

}
}

In this section i'm calling just one Extra Food so i can return inside a list in the other section

```
if (_con.product.extraGroups == null)
                        CircularLoadingWidget(height: 100)
                      else
                        ListView.separated(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                          controller: ScrollController(initialScrollOffset: 600),
                          itemBuilder: (context, extraGroupIndex) {
                            var extraGroup = _con.product.extraGroups.elementAt(extraGroupIndex);
                            return Wrap(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                ListTile(
                                  dense: true,
                                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0),
                                  leading: Icon(
                                      Icons.add_circle_outline,
                                      color: Theme.of(context).accentColor
                                  ),
                                  title: Text(
                                    extraGroup?.name ?? '',
                                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1.merge(TextStyle(
                                        color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                        fontSize: 16
                                    )),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              
                                Container(
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  ),
                                  child: ListTile(
                                    title:Text('Seleccione su ${extraGroup.name}',
                                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption.merge(TextStyle(
                                          color: Theme.of(context).shadowColor,
                                          //fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                          fontSize: 13
                                      )),
                                    ),
                                   
                                    trailing: FlatButton(
                                      color: Theme.of(context).focusColor.withOpacity(0.4),
                                      shape:RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)
                                      ),
                                      onPressed:(){
                                        showModalBottomSheet(
                                            isScrollControlled: true,
                                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(30),topRight: Radius.circular(30))
                                            ),
                                            context: context,
                                            builder: (context){
                                              return Wrap(
                                                children: [
                                                  Padding(
                                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                                    child: SizedBox(
                                                      child: ListView.separated(
                                                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                                                        itemBuilder: (context, extraIndex) {
                                                          return ExtraItemWidget(
                                                            extra: _con.product.extras.where((extra) => extra.extraGroupId == extraGroup.id && extra.multiple_selection == true ).elementAt(extraIndex),
                                                            onChanged: _con.calculateTotal,
                                                          );
                                                        },
                                                        separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                                                          return SizedBox(height: 0);
                                                        },
                                                        itemCount: _con.product.extras.where((extra) => extra.extraGroupId == extraGroup.id && extra.multiple_selection == true).length,
                                                        primary: false,
                                                        shrinkWrap: true,
                                                      ),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                  Padding(
                                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                                    child: ListView.builder(
                                                      itemBuilder: (context, extraIndex) {
                                                    
                                                        return ExtraSingleItemWidget(
                                                          extra: _con.product.extras.where((extra) => extra.extraGroupId == extraGroup.id && extra.multiple_selection == false).elementAt(extraIndex),
                                                          onChanged: _con.calculateTotal,
                                                          onSelectedExtra: _con.SelectedExtra,
                                                        );
                                                 

                                                      },
                                                  
                                                      itemCount: _con.product.extras.where((extra) => extra.extraGroupId == extraGroup.id && extra.multiple_selection == false).length,
                                                      primary: false,
                                                      shrinkWrap: true,
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ],
                                              );
                                            });
                                      },
                                      child: Wrap(
                                        children: [
                                          Text(
                                            'Seleccionar',
                                            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.button.merge(TextStyle(
                                                color: Theme.of(context).shadowColor
                                            )),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            );
                          },
                          separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return Divider(thickness:1.5,height: 20);
                          },
                          itemCount: _con.product.extraGroups.length,
                          primary: false,
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                        ),
```

I'm calling like ExtraSingleItemWidget, once the user select an extra it add to the base price but if the user want to select another extra from the modal bottom sheet it select more than one and I just need one at a time.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YI7L3.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hoee.png)

Comment: if I understand well, you just need to make the value of other choices equals false then setState((){}).

Comment: @ammar i did it but i'm using just one RadioListTile that is in ExtraSingleItemWidget, and my values doesn't work

Comment: You have a list of items and you want that user can select multiple items as well right?

Comment: @Diwyansh no what i want to do is to select just one item at a time